# How to declare a variable's type as class that inherits/extends from a base class in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

*I must apologize if this question is duplicated, but I googled first without getting a useful answer.*

##### Typescript is quite new to me, today I have met a problem of it.

### Scenario

In typescript, I have a base class:

```js
abstract class Animal {
    // Animal class definition here
    // ...
}
```

And I have several sub-classes that inherits from `Animal` class:

```js
class Cat extends Animal {
    // Cat class definition here
    jump() { console.log('Cat jumps high like a cat.') }
    // ...
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    // Dog class definition here
    swim() { console.log('Dog swims like a dog.') }
    // ...
}
```

### Question

How can I declare a variable whose type is the sub-class of Animal in typescript?
like this, but it is not working code:

```js
let animal: any extends Animal = new Cat();
animal.jump(); // typescript will warn me: "Property 'jump' does not exist on type 'Animal'"
```

or like this in java, which is java's working code:

```java
// java code
Animal animal = new Cat();
animal.jump();
```

### Trivia

`let animal: Cat | Dog = new Cat();` is not a good answer, because I may implement more sub-classes that extends from `Animal` class in the future.
Also, I did not merely want to declare a variable like I did above (in that case, I can just use `let animal = new Cat();`), in fact, this is the actual scenario I have encountered:

```js
class House {
    private animalThatStaysIn; // what type should I declare for this member? I think it is the class that inherits/extends from Animal
    constructor(animal) {
        this.animalThatStaysIn = animal;
    }
}
let cat = new Cat();
let catHouse = new House(cat);
let dog = new Dog();
let dogHouse = new House(dog);
```

What's more, I cannot change the definition of `Cat` or `Dog` class for they are from my external import(node_modules folder).

Comment: Your Java code will generate the same type of error as your TypeScript code.

Comment: The question is a little confusing, but if you want to use inheritance to categorize animals as "jumping animals" or "house animals" , you need to account for that in your type hierarchy by introducing additional classes, interfaces or union types. If you don't, then you need to either do a type check or use a type assertion before calling the concrete function.

Comment: My question is quite simple, I just want a typescript grammar that can inform me that the `animalThatStaysIn` member has the type that inherits from `Animal` class, is there one?

Comment: Yes. Just `Animal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are your options:

#### 1. Add additional types in the type hierarchy

```
abstract class Animal {}

abstract class JumpingAnimal {
  abstract jump(): void;
}

abstract class SwimmingAnimal {
  abstract swim(): void;
}

class Cat extends JumpingAnimal {
  jump() { console.log('Jumping like a cat'); }
}

class Fish extends SwimmingAnimal {
  swim() { console.log('Swimming like a fish'); }
}

const cat: JumpingAnimal = new Cat();
cat.jump();
```

#### 2. Use [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) to define common behavior

```
abstract class Animal {}

interface Jumper {
  jump: () => void;
}

interface Swimmer {
  swim: () => void;
}

class Cat extends Animal implements Jumper {
  jump() { console.log('Jumping like a cat'); }
}

class Fish extends Animal implements Swimmer {
  swim() { console.log('Swimming like a fish'); }
}

const cat: Animal & Jumper = new Cat();
cat.jump();
```

This has the additional benefit that you can use [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) to specify multiple interfaces:

```
class Dog extends Animal implements Jumper, Swimmer {
  jump() { console.log('Jumping like a cat'); }
  swim() { console.log('Swimming like a fish'); }
}

const dog: Animal & Jumper & Swimmer = new Dog();
dog.jump();
dog.swim();
```

#### 3. Use [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) to create type categories

```
type JumpingAnimal = Dog | Cat;

const cat: JumpingAnimal = new Cat();
cat.jump();
```

#### 4. Use type guards to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#instanceof-narrowing) the type

```
const cat: Animal = new Cat();

if (cat instanceof Cat) {
  cat.jump(); // no error
}
```

#### 5. Use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler: "Trust me, I know what I'm doing"

```
const cat: Animal = new Cat();
(cat as Dog).swim(); // runtime error
```

Or some combination of the above.

Comment: Yes, this is better solution regarding to OOP principles.

Answer (score 0):

You have a design problem. You are missing an intermediate type: `HouseAnimal` (or `Pet`). Your actual design should be something like this:

```
abstract class Animal {
    // Animal class definition here
    // ...
}

abstract class HouseAnimal extends Animal {
    // Features only house animals have
}

class Cat extends HouseAnimal {}

class Dog extends HouseAnimal {}

class House {
    private animals: HouseAnimal
}
```

This is probably the most correct approach using inheritance. Alternatively you could also make house animals have certain features that non-house-animals have if you don't want an intermediate type. To enforce this in the type system you can use an interface:

```
abstract class Animal {
    // Animal class definition here
    // ...
}

interface HouseAnimal {
    // These animals can be in houses
}

class Cat extends Animal implements HouseAnimal {}

class Dog extends Animal implements HouseAnimal {}

class House {
    private animals: HouseAnimal
}
```

Comment: How come this is gonna help? He will not be able to invoke jump() method anyhow.

Comment: @FatihErsoy You need to continue reading his question. His actual problem is not calling `.jump()`. His actual problem is allowing only some animals in the house

Comment: I don't think this is the case. He wants to inject an abstract class that consists all animals, but he wants to use specific animal's methods in the house also. He complains that if he injects Animal class into the house, he won't be able to invoke jump() method or any other specific animal's method (like swim()).

Comment: You are right, @slebetman , but I cannot change the definition of Cat or Dog class for they are from my external import (node_modules folder). And I only want a typescript grammar that can inform me that the `animalThatStaysIn` member has the type that inherits from Animal class.

Comment: @Paper_Folding Is there any feature/method/property that `Cat` and `Dog` have that non-house-animals don't have?